# how to filter related tables by date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 related tables and I need to filter the date of a table by month

My first table have the following fields: Id_agendamien_persona , Id_agendamiento, id_persona

The second table have the following fields: Id_agendamiento, fecha

so I need to filter fecha in the second table,

**Mi controller**

```
public function listar(){

        $contactos = Contacto::pluck('completo','id_contacto');
        $contacto_x_agendamientos =  Contacto_x_Agendamiento::all();
        array_add($contactos,0,"::Seleccione::");

        return view('agendamiento.listar')->with(compact('contacto_x_agendamientos','contactos'));

    }
```

My model

**first table**

```
   class Contacto_x_Agendamiento extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "contacto_x_agendamiento";
        protected $primaryKey = 'id_contacto_x_agendamiento';
        const CREATED_AT = 'fecha_creado';
        const UPDATED_AT = 'fecha_modificado';

        public function Agendamiento(){
            return $this->hasOne(Agendamiento::class,'id_agendamiento','id_agendamiento');
        }

}
```

**second table**

```
class Agendamiento extends Model
{
    protected $table = "agendamiento";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_agendamiento';
    const CREATED_AT = 'fecha_creado';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'fecha_modificado';


    public function scopeMes($query){
        return $query->whereMonth('fecha_agendar','=',date('m'))->get();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<td>{{$contacto_x_agendamiento->Agendamiento->Mes()->fecha_agendar}}</td>
```

error

> Property [fecha_agendar] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here, is that you're trying to fetch the property of an `Agendamiento` model from a `Collection` that you're getting back as a result.

Here you have two choices. You either get just one model, by using `->first()`:

```
echo $contacto_x_agendamiento->Agendamiento->Mes()->first()->fecha_agendar;
```

Or you iterate the `Collection` and print each `fecha_agendar` property:

```
foreach ($contacto_x_agendamiento->Agendamiento->Mes()->get() as $agendamiento) {
    echo $agendamiento->fecha_agendar;
}
```

On a side note, you should totally rethink your coding style/conventions. I'm fully aware it works, but having `id_contacto_x_agendamiento` as a primary id or a class name like `Contacto_x_Agendamiento` isn't best practice.

Having a mix of English and Spanish in classes/properties/variables could also be avoided, to improve other people's readability.